# How can I tell WebSphere wsadmin to run a python package rather than a single python file?

Tags: python, websphere

I'm trying to create a jython package that will allow the user to conduct some WebSphere actions from the command line.  I'm using jython as the language and specify the file to run with the call to wsadmin.

Now though, my jython file is getting rather large and I'd like to start splitting it into multiple modules.  However, whenever I try to call `import` and ask for one of the other jython modules, which would be adjacent to the original module, I get an error.  I'm guessing this is because wsadmin doesn't know about those modules.

Is there a way to specify a directory of python modules or maybe some sort of classpath akin to Java to tell wsadmin where it should really be getting my extra modules?  If not, is there a good way or maybe a utility that would allow me to compress multiple modules to a single script?

I call wsadmin like this:

```
wsadmin -lang jython -f file.py
```